# jQuery show() vs adding Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

Which of these is more efficient (i.e. faster):

```
$(elem).show();
```

or

```
$(elem).addClass(displayClass); // Where display class is "display: block;"
```

Or are they identical?

Comment: Which is faster to add a "display:block;" then remove it if you do that, or just to change none to block?

Answer (score 20):

It depends what you're after, they do different things:

- `$(elem).show();` - shows the element, restoring the `display` from before [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) or restoring the default `display` for the element type
- `$(elem).addClass(displayClass);` - adds a class, always with a certain `display`, not really restoring what *was* there - this is less flexible

---

Which is *faster*? [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) hands down, [you can test it yourself here](http://jsperf.com/show-vs-addclass), it simply [does a lot less work](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/attributes.js#L39) than [`.show()` does](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/effects.js#L17).  However, it doesn't do as much feature-wise, so it's less flexible for the reasons above.

Comment: This is function execution comparison between show and addClass. What about CSSDOM recomputation time?

Answer (score 7):

No, they are absolutely **not** identical.

There's a **big** difference between direct modifications to element styles and "indirect" modifications by changing the element's class, and that really should be pretty obvious. By writing cooperative code between Javascript and CSS, the class changes give you a lot more flexibility. The Javascript manages the *state* of elements, while the CSS drives the actual *effect* of that state.

The `show()` and `hide()` methods are handy and easy, but (in my opinion) managing state/appearance by class name is really a much more powerful and maintainable way to do things. In fact you can always write your own little jQuery plugins to add/remove classes that are meaningful to your app, to avoid having the class names themselves propagate through your code.

Answer (score 0):

They're not identical; they work completely differently. They may in your case have the same effect, but don't count on it.

For example, `addClass` may not actually make the element visible in all cases. If the element has other styles which supercede the class (eg ID-level CSS, or inline styles, etc), then adding a class won't have any effect at all.

Also, setting `display:block` is only correct for elements that you want to be displayed as a block. If you've got inline elements (or worse, tables) and you try to display them as block, the results will probably not be what you're expecting.

Finally, `.addClass()` definitely involves more processing for the browser than `.show()`, so you're not making things any easier for your site by using it.

In short, if that's all you're trying to achieve, use `.show()` - it's the correct jQuery way to do it.

Comment: addClass definitely does not involve more processing as @Pointy showed in his jsperf test. In fact, I think it would be a better idea for people to implement a custom show/hide that used `addClass` & `removeClass` underneath the hood.